# Suppose $a$ is a real number for which all the roots of the equation are real. Find a bound on $a$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

Suppose $a$ is a real number for which all the roots of the equation $x^{4} - 2ax^{2}+x+a^{2}-a=0$ are real. Then

(a) $\quad a<-\frac{2}{3}$

(b) $\quad a=0$

(c) $\quad 0<a<\frac{3}{4}$

(d) $\quad a\ge \frac{3}{4}$

Comment: For these problems that are multiple choice, it suffices to simply choose a few values.  For example, it's easy to see this won't be true if $a=0$.

Comment: I guess that's true, since all of the options have am empty intersection, it should be fine.

Comment: Of course, choose easy values, like $a=1,-1$...

Comment: This question can be solved without having to do much algebra if you know what the graph of the quartic $f(x) = (x^2-a)^2$ looks like. Maybe I'll write an answer up later (drawing pictures on computer takes some time).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solve $a$ in terms of $x$ first,

\begin{align*}
  a^2-(2x^2+1)a+x^4+x &= 0 \\
  a &= \frac{2x^2+1\pm \sqrt{(2x^2+1)^2-4(x^4+x)}}{2} \\
  &= \frac{2x^2+1 \pm \sqrt{4x^2-4x+1}}{2} \\
  &= \frac{2x^2+1 \pm (2x-1)}{2} \\
  &= x^2 \pm x+\frac{1\mp 1}{2} \\
  &= x^2+x \qquad \text{or} \qquad x^2-x+1 \\
  x^4-2ax^2+x+a^2-a &= (x^2+x-a)(x^2-x-a+1)
\end{align*}

---

**Case I:** $x^2+x-a=0$
\begin{align*}
  \Delta &\ge 0 \\
  1+4a &\ge 0 \\
  a &\ge -\frac{1}{4}
\end{align*}

**Case II:** $x^2-x-a+1=0$
\begin{align*}
  \Delta &\ge 0 \\
  1+4(a-1) &\ge 0 \\
  a &\ge \frac{3}{4}
\end{align*}

---

> For **all** roots to be real,
>
> $$a\in \left[ -\frac{1}{4}, \infty \right) \cap \left[ \frac{3}{4}, \infty \right)$$
>
> $$\fbox{$a\ge \frac{3}{4}$}$$

See another answer [**here**](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1926750/solve-the-equation-x-sqrta-sqrtax-a-geq-1/1926806#1926806).