# Solve $\sqrt{3+\sqrt{3+x}}=x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Solve
>   $$\sqrt{3+\sqrt{3+x}}=x$$

My try:

$$\sqrt{3+\sqrt{3+x}}=x \\ 
3+\sqrt{3+x}=x^2\\\sqrt{3+x}=x^2-3\\3+x=(x^2-3)^2$$

$$x^4-6x^2+9=x+3\\x^4-6x^2-x+6=0$$

Now ?

Comment: You don't need absolute value at the end. $(\sqrt x)^2 = x$ and $x+3\geq 0$ anyway.

Comment: @Ennar. ok ....

Comment: Note that x=1 is solution of the last line but not the first. You have included extra roots in the few lines of math.

Comment: You sound unconvinced about Ennar's comment., while normally $(\sqrt{x})^2=|x|$, here we notice that $x=\sqrt{\text{something}}$ and $\sqrt{\text{something}}$ is always greater than or equal to zero in the case we are limiting our attention to the real numbers, so we know $x\geq 0$ and therefore $|x|=x$

Comment: Note that with $y:=\sqrt{3+x}$, what we need is $\sqrt{3+y}=x$.

Comment: @Arthur: No, the $x$ disappeared

Comment: Solve the Quadratic equation

Comment: @JMoravitz, $(\sqrt x)^2=|x|$ is true, but there is no need for absolute value. (Real) square root is right inverse of $\cdot^2\colon \mathbb R\to\mathbb R_{\geq 0}$ by definition.

Comment: Just noticed the $x$ in the equation my bad

Comment: Similar post: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1926750/321264.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no need to deal with any quartic equation in $x$. The key is the function
on LHS $x \mapsto \sqrt{ 3 + \sqrt{3+x}}$ is a composition of the map 
$x \mapsto \sqrt{3+x}$ with itself.

The map $x \mapsto \sqrt{3+x}$ is strictly increasing whenever it is defined (i.e $x \ge -3$)

If $\sqrt{3+x} > x$, then $\sqrt{3 + \sqrt{3+x}} > \sqrt{3+x} > x$.

If $\sqrt{3+x} < x$, then $\sqrt{3 + \sqrt{3+x}} < \sqrt{3+x} < x$.

If we want $\sqrt{3 + \sqrt{3+x}} = x$, we need  $\sqrt{3+x} = x$. This leads to
$$x^2 = 3 + x \iff x^2- x - 3 = 0 \implies x = \frac{1 \pm \sqrt{13}}{2}$$

Since $x = \sqrt{3 + \sqrt{3 + x}}$ is supposed to be non-negative, 
$x = \frac{1 + \sqrt{13}}{2}$ is the only possible solution (and it does work).

Answer (score 3):

$$\sqrt{3+x}=x^2-3$$
$$3+x=(x^2-3)^2$$
$$x^4 -6x^2 +9 -x - 3=x^4 -6x^2-x+6=0$$
$$(x-1)(x+2)(x^2-x-3)=0$$

None of $1, -2, \frac{1-\sqrt{13}}{2}$ are not answers, due to our double-squaring. Basically, we need the following inequalities to be true:

$$x+3 \ge 0$$
$$x\ge 0$$
$$\sqrt{3+x} = x^2 - 3 \ge 0$$

Thus $x \ge \sqrt{3}$, and $x=\frac{1+\sqrt{13}}{2}$

Comment: x=1 not a solution, neither is x=-2

Comment: And now, the false solutions created by the successive squarings are ... and the unique true solution is...

Comment: how ? $x^4-6x^2-x+6=(x-1)(x+2)(x^2-x-3)$

Comment: @Almot1960, you guess the integer solutions and then do polynomial division. It's easy to guess them since they must divide $6$. Please see [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_test).

Comment: @Did good point, it's worth to dig in to the final answer, instead of stopping there.

Comment: @Almot1960 yea, I mostly observed and tried. Did not follow any methodology to do the factorization.

Answer (score 3):

First state the conditions that $x$ has to satisfy:

- The initial equation requires $x\ge 0$.
- $\sqrt{3+x}=x^2-3$ requires $x^2\ge 3$, i.e., taking into account the previous condition, $x\ge \sqrt3$.
  The resulting equation is easy to factorise: rewrite it as
  \begin{align}
  x^4-x-6x^2+6&=x(x^3-1)-6(x^2-1)=(x-1)\bigl(x(x^2+x+1)-6(x+1)\bigr)\\&=(x-1)(x^3+x^2-5x-6).
  \end{align}
  One tests the existence of rational roots for the second factor, among $\pm1, \pm2,\pm3,\pm6$, one finds $-2$, so dividing by $x+2$:
  $$x^4-x-6x^2+6=(x-1)(x+2)(x^2-x-3).$$
  Set $p(x)=x^2-x-3$. Its discriminant is $\Delta=13$. As $p(\sqrt 3)=-\sqrt 3<0$, $\sqrt 3$ separates the roots, so the only root $\ge\sqrt3$ is
  $$x=\frac{1+\sqrt{13}}2.$$

Answer (score 1):

We have to factorize $x^4 - 6x^2 - x + 6 = 0.$

We would observe that the values of x would be $1,-2,\frac{1±\sqrt{13}}{2}$.

Comment: Anything missing or needed?

Comment: We need to test the validity of those roots.